# Bug in the Unity Animator Inspector. Can't see any the values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I can't see anything in Animator Inspector:

[image: picture]

How to fix it?

Comment: Looks all there to me. What do you think is missing.

Comment: @BugFinder I think in the Inspector there should be fields for the selected state

Comment: @derhugo i seem to recall to see some of the portions of the animator you almost need to be in full screen mode. And that its almost its own inspector not that inspector if that makes sense

Comment: the inspector just wont show, i have the "Run_static" selected and its meant  to show the inspector but it just wont.

Comment: @BugFinder not really tbh, [this](https://imgur.com/a/oj8xDRS) is an example of the Inspecto in size about `400 x 275` pixels having the editor itself windowed quite small around `1400 x 800` (my display is 4K UHD). OP does this still happening when closing and reopening Unity or maybe even reboot your device (the good old turn it off and on again)?

Comment: I'm in full screen, i have closed unity and opened it again, and i believe I'm up to date, the only thing that i have not done is buy the pro version.

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch to inspector debug mode. You can do this by clicking the three-dot menu on the right side of the inspector tab. Once clicked, you should see a "Debug" mode. Switch to "Debug" mode, and you should now be able to see your inspector fields.